# Android - touch drawing

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, touch

I am looking at [this sample drawing app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html) by Google, and when I run the app in the simulator and try to draw with my mouse, the drawing does not appear smoothly. The circles are appearing with gaps between them. Only when I drag my mouse slowly I get a unbroken line. I don't yet have an actual device to test this on, so I want to know if this is how it will be on the actual device also, or is this a simulator behavior?

If this is how it will appear on the device also, what should I do to make the touch drawing smooth?

**UPDATE:**

The actual code that does the drawing is:

```
private void drawPoint(float x, float y, float pressure, float width) {
    if (width < 1) width = 6; 
    if (mBitmap != null) {
        float radius = width / 2;
        int pressureLevel = (int)(pressure * 255);
        mPaint.setARGB(pressureLevel, 255, 255, 255);
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaint);
        mRect.set((int) (x - radius - 2), (int) (y - radius - 2),
                (int) (x + radius + 2), (int) (y + radius + 2));
        invalidate(mRect);
    }
}

@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {         
    int N = event.getHistorySize();
    int P = event.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++) {
            mCurX = event.getHistoricalX(j, i);
            mCurY = event.getHistoricalY(j, i);
            drawPoint(mCurX, mCurY,
                    event.getHistoricalPressure(j, i),
                    event.getHistoricalTouchMajor(j, i));
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < P; j++) {
        mCurX = event.getX(j);
        mCurY = event.getY(j);
        drawPoint(mCurX, mCurY, event.getPressure(j), event.getTouchMajor(j));
    }           
}
```

Any help in improving it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @Hello Sir,can you tell where you are bring this mCanvas ?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question?

Answer (score 2):

It will be jagged, but I believe that code is drawing points, so if you just draw a line, starting where the last end was drawn to the new point, it will be continuous.

And yes, it will look the same way on an actual device.

The other option, which I am doing from memory, is there was some pressure value that was between 0 and 255, or 0 and 1, set it to the highest value, all the time.  That may actually be a simple solution to your problem.

It would help if you show the code that is actually doing the drawing, btw.

**UPDATE:**

As I mentioned change this line:

```
int pressureLevel = (int)(pressure * 255);
```

to

```
int pressureLevel = (int)(255);
```

should fix your problem.

If that doesn't then rather than using `drawCircle` you may want to just use `drawLine`, then you would keep track of the last circle you had just drawn.

Comment: I have just updated my question with the code. Any help in improving it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried setting pressureLevel to 255 and also, tried using drawLine - but it still looks jagged on the emulator.. I am inclined to think it's probably because of the emulator's rendering. I have to get an actual device to try this out.

In addition, the drawLine() looks worse than drawCircle() because with the drawLine(), the bits are joins using thick squarish lines, which does not flow well.

Comment: You can change the width of the line, but drawline will look more jagged, as I mentioned.  You can also draw circles in between, to fix this.  I don't remember exactly how I resolved this but if you looked at the dimensions as you draw two circles, if there are empty spots, then just draw the missing circles.  If you drew rectangles it would probably look better than circles, btw I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better run on device not emulator, since emulator processing the real-time action is too slow :).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
   if (event.getHistorySize() == 0) {
      x = event.getX();
      y = event.getY();
   }
   if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
     x = event.getX();
     y = event.getY();
   }

   bitmapCanvas.drawLine(x, y, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
   x = event.getX();
   y = event.getY();
   invalidate();
   return true;
}
```

Some things have to be improved, but in general this is good for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method that's supposed to fix this problem,
When you define the mPaint attributes try:

```
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
```

This attributes joins the "jagged lines" into a nice smooth line.